# How can I limit a JavaScript .filter result?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

I'm creating a simple shopping cart in JavaScript as an exercise. I'm using .filter to remove a product (object) by ID when the user clicks to remove one item from the cart (array). However, of course, .filter will remove all objects with the ID of x from the array. I believe the best way to achieve what I'm looking for is to remove a maximum of one object with said ID from the array of objects. Is anyone aware of how to do this / a more apt solution?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/LiamMacmillan/zryq62ua/79/

```
let thisItemId = $(this).parent().data("id");

shoppingCart = shoppingCart.filter(
    item => item.id != thisItemId
);
```

Comment: Why are there multiple items with the same id in your shopping cart in the first place?

Comment: _"An identifier is a name that identifies (that is, labels the identity of) either a unique object or a unique class of objects, where the "object" or class may be an idea, physical countable object (or class thereof), or physical noncountable substance (or class thereof). The abbreviation ID often refers to identity"_ [Identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identifier) Each item in your cart should have an unique item it. It's usually not the product ID.

Comment: Yeah, far from ideal. Still seeing how this all works out, and will ensure to change this. Thank you both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) and [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice):

```
const index = shoppingCart.findIndex(item => item.id === thisItemId);
if (index > -1) {
  shoppingCart.splice(index, 1);
}
```

---

It might be better to keep track of a count of each item in your shopping cart though, will be much easier to display to the user, and makes this situation simpler to manage.

an example of what this might look like

```
let shoppingCart = [
  { itemId: 1, count: 5 },
  { itemId: 2, count: 3 }
];

function decreaseCount(itemId) {
  const shoppingCartItem = shoppingCart.find(x => x.itemId === itemId);
  if (shoppingCartItem) {
    if (--shoppingCartItem.count < 1) {
      removeItem(itemId);
    }
  }
}

// slightly less efficient, but uses immutable objects, map, and filter
function decreaseCountImmutable(itemId) {
  shoppingCart = 
   shoppingCart
     .map(x =>  x.itemId !== itemId ? x: ({ ...x, count: x.count -1 }))
     .filter(x => x.count > 0);
}

function increaseCount(itemId) {
  const shoppingCartItem = shoppingCart.find(x => x.itemId === itemId);
  if (shoppingCartItem) {
    shoppingCartItem.count++;
  } else {
    shoppingCart.push({ itemId, count: 1 });
  }
}

// uses immutable objects and map
function increaseCountImmutable(itemId) {
  let foundItem = false;
  shoppingCart = shoppingCart.map(x =>  x.itemId !== itemId ? x: (foundItem = true) && ({ ...x, count: x.count + 1 }));
  if (!foundItem) {
    shoppingCart.push({ itemId, count: 1 });
  } 
}

function removeItem(itemId) {
  shoppingCart = shoppingCart.filter(x => x.itemId !== itemId);
}
```

Comment: The assignment `shoppingCart = shoppingCart.splice(index, 1);` won't work. `splice` mutates the array it is called on, and returns the removed values.

Comment: Btw, the representation with the item count, one can (and should) use `map` and `filter` quite nicely.

Comment: Adding a count to each item is a much better solution, so thank you. Can anyone potentially provide an example with map and filter? I can’t seem to get it working.

Comment: @LiamMacmillan I'll update this one to address all the comments and change my example to use map/filter instead.

Comment: @CallumMorrisson Thank you, much appreciated. I decided to simply directly increment the count in the object array, like so: https://jsfiddle.net/LiamMacmillan/zryq62ua/127/